# PHP Try Catch not working for pg_query()

Tags: php, postgresql, try-catch

I'm trying to handle SQL query errors with `pg_query()` function.

The code:

```
    try{
            $result = pg_query($dbconn,"SET application_name = 'testing text'");
            echo $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

Wonder why still I'm getting following warning message from pg_query() line.

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration
>   parameter "application_name" in...

I'm try to stop that Warning. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: to silence the warning message, prepend @ to pg_query: `$result=@pg_query(...);`

Comment: You might also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/q/22743357/398670 - it's about PDO, but it's relevant to error handling with regular `pg_query` as well.

Comment: Thanks Deniel, but @ pg_query removed the error completely. I want to catch that error. But can't catch it with using @ pg_query.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I can't catch that error when use PDO object. I'm trying to do the same thing with pg_query(). Still no luck.